# Find every object value with x key and change type of value

Tags: javascript, object

I want to find every data.id in an object like this and change the type from a number to a string.

```
myData = {
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "data":
            {
                "id": 1,
            }
    },
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "data": 
            {
                "id": 5,
            }
    }
}
```

I tried something simple like this just to test and it doesn't work:

```
JSON.stringify(myData[0].data.id);
console.log(typeof(myData[0].data.id)); output: number
```

I'm guessing I have to use Array.map()?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is `myData` supposed to be an array? What you've written is not legal JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myData should be an array but in your case it is an object. I wonder how your above code is working. If it is an array then to change that value you can iterate over the array and do something like this

```
for(let i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    myData[i].userId = myData[i].userId.toString()
}
```

The reason your code is not working is because JSON.stringify returns a new value not changes the current value.

Answer (score 1):

The `JSON.stringify` method does not change the value you pass, it just returns the json version of the element.

I suggest this:

`myData[0].data.id = myData[0].data.id.toString();`

or

`myData[0].data.id = '' + myData[0].data.id;`